# Выделение памяти для массива

Tags: массивы, память, структуры, c

Как выделить память через t для массива `a[5]`?

```
struct x{
    /* ... */
    int *t;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    struct { int *t; } x;

    /*
        Вызываем malloc с параметром,
        равным размеру элемента помноженному на их количество.
        После присваивания x.t указывает на память под массив из 5 элементов int.
    */
    x.t = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: а если через  new это сделать?

Comment: Это уже С++, а в тегах его нет. x.t = new int[5]